# rustc false positive warning about value never read?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, false-positive

Following [this article](https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/build-your-own-shell-rust/) about writing a shell in Rust. Compiler outputs a warning about a variable never being read.

```
use std::io::stdin;
use std::io::stdout;
use std::io::Write;
use std::process::Command;
use std::path::Path;

 fn main(){
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
            print!("> ");
            stdout().flush().unwrap();
//              input = String::from("");  //  **<===== HERE**
            stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
            let mut parts = input.trim().split_whitespace();
            let command = parts.next().unwrap();
            let args = parts;
            match command {
                "cd" => {
                    let new_dir = args.peekable().peek().map_or("/", |x| *x);
                    let root = Path::new(new_dir);
                    if let Err(e) = std::env::set_current_dir(&root) {
                        eprintln!("{}", e);
                    }
                },
                "exit" => return,
                command => {
                    let child = Command::new(command)
                        .args(args)
                        .spawn();
                    // gracefully handle malformed user input
                    match child {
                        Ok(mut child) => { child.wait().unwrap(); },
                        Err(e) => eprintln!("{}", e),
                    };
               }
           }
    }
}
```

However, commenting out this line causes program to bug: here is the behavior before and after commenting:

```
usn@DESKTOP:~/bqy/rust/p2$ cargo run
warning: value assigned to `input` is never read
 --> src/main.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     let mut input = String::new();
  |             ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
  = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running `target/debug/p2`
> ls
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  src  target
> ls
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  src  target
> exit
usn@DESKTOP:~/bqy/rust/p2$ vi src/main.rs
usn@DESKTOP:~/bqy/rust/p2$ cargo run
   Compiling p2 v0.1.0 (/mnt/d/MMM/projects/bqy/rust/p2)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.13s
     Running `target/debug/p2`
> ls
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  src  target
> ls
ls: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
> exit
ls: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'exit': No such file or directory
> ^C
usn@DESKTOP:~/bqy/rust/p2$ vi src/main.rs
```

Simple explanation of unwanted behavior is that command line is not resetted. So, why does the compiler complains ?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126581/how-can-i-get-user-input-without-receiving-an-unsed-variable-warning  doesn't answer the problem .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a let-rebinding and a standard assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323500/what-is-the-difference-between-a-let-rebinding-and-a-standard-assignment)

Comment: Why do you want to assign it to empty string instead of making a new string each time? The article shows using String::new each time. The compiler might be saying you are setting the value to empty string then overwriting that value - so - the assignment to empty string is never used.

Comment: Using `let mut input = ...` inside your loop you create a completely new variable and the `input` declared outside of the loop is never used. TL;DR: inside the loop, keep the `input = String::new()` line, lose the one with `let mut input = ...`

Comment: @BrianWalker Because it is cheaper to make a string once in initialization time, then just resetting it at every loop ? For example, in C code, I always thought it was cheaper to declare a variable before a loop, so the compiler deals with the memory allocation only once (and writing/clearing etc at a already known location)

Comment: Don't use `input = String::new()`, use `input.clear()`.

Comment: @justinas I suppose the `String::new()` made me afraid. Like a C++ `new` . Isn't better to create variable once ?

Comment: `String::new()` doesn't allocate (most empty collections don't allocate in Rust). But I don't see how whether this allocates or not is relevant to your problem.

Comment: @justinas Thx for the link, but it didn't answered this question, because here I didn't use `let`inside the loop. But can be useful for similar problems :) !

Comment: "always thought it was cheaper to declare a variable before a loop, so the compiler deals with the memory allocation only once" modern compilers are very smart in preliminary optimizations like this, so there's probably no need to worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the line to clear the buffer, its content is reused from one iteration to another. This is why your program doesn't work without

```
input = String::from("");
```

But this gives you a warning because you gave `input` a value when you declared it:

```
let mut input = String::new();
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and this value is *not* used, since literally the first use of `input` is to override it. So just don't give it a value:

```
let mut input;
```

In Rust this is perfectly safe and the compiler won't let you accidentally use `input` before you initialize it.

---

Alternatively, if you goal was to reuse the buffer to save on memory, you should use

```
input.clear();
```

because `input = String::from("");` creates a completely new string with a new buffer and throws the other one away.

Comment: Thanks. 1) My error was to think that it was mandatory to declare `input` with some value in order to let the compiler figure out it is a string. 2) Last sentence, are you sure ? Doesn't just "overwrite" the buffer with an empty one ?

Comment: @ymudyruc About 2): Yes, assignment is not an operator in Rust like it is in C++, so `a = b;` always _replaces_ the value, throwing away whatever was there in the first place. The [`Clone::clone_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#method.clone_from) method or specific methods like `String::clear` have to be used.

Comment: Oh... with 2 years xp writing C++ code, learning Rust seems to be not so obvious :)  Btw, if someone knows a good reference, to avoid such pitfalls for C++-experienced, that could interest me !

Comment: @ymudyruc Note that the "as-if" rule still applies: although Rust is bound to behave _as if_ `a = b` replaced the value of `a` and threw away the old one, it doesn't mean that the compiler won't optimize things if it can prove that you can't observe the difference. For example, in case of a string, whose `Drop` does nothing except deallocate memory, the optimizer might completely elide the creation of the original string. It's not something you can rely on happening, but you also can't rely on it _not_ happening.

Comment: @ymudyruc As for a good reference, see the [O'Reilly book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust/9781491927274/). It was written by experienced C++ developers, contains a lot of C++ references, and is a great intro to the language.